# Decorating domain objects in ServiceStack with Onion Architecture

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack, onion-architecture

I'm learning ServiceStack and Onion Architecture, and I have a question that seems so basic I feel I'm missing something.

I have three projects, an Api, Core, and Infrastructure.

I have ServiceStack in an API project.  I have my entity objects in my Core project, my data access classes are in my Infrastructure project.  I have to decorate my entity objects with attributes so that the Orm Lite code knows how to act with them (creating tables, etc).  These are attributes like [AutoIncrement] and [Index].

I have to reference ServiceStack in my core to get access to the attributes, and core, up to this point, hasn't had a dependency on anything, and this breaks the idea of the Onion Architecture.

What am I missing?  How do I allow OrmLite in the Infrastructure project to handle the data access for my entities while the entities are in core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with Ormlite. I have created a ticket long time back to move the Attributes to the common assembly but the code change did not happen yet. If you can move the attributes to the common assembly and do a pull request, we will have it added.

Comment: Hey Guru, check out the [OrmLite v4 update](https://plus.google.com/106787359118990653189/posts/Sbd5113dRrd). All attributes have now been moved to ServiceStack.Interfaces and where possible they're weakly-linked by name (i.e. so you could use System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations instead). It's also now possible to [add attributes at runtime](http://bit.ly/1e5IQqS) i.e. disconnected from the POCOs.

Comment: Thanks Demis. I'm still using 3.x thats why I havent seen those changes.

Comment: Thanks @guru-kathiresan and mythz ... glad to see I wasn't just missing something big.